# Which one is fast when I want to SQL round up (Round, Module(%), Floor)?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to round up the value to nearest 5. There are several ways you can do this. just wonder which one is fast. Is there a any effect to make this code slower

```
DECLARE @number int = 104

SELECT (ROUND( @number / 5,0 ) * 5 ) + 5    -- 1
SELECT CEILING( @number / 5.0 ) * 5     -- 2
SELECT ((@number/5)*5) + 5              -- 3

DECLARE @remainder int                  -- 4
SET @remainder = ( @number % 5);

IF @remainder = 0
    SELECT @number
ELSE
    SELECT @number -  @remainder + 5
```

Comment: [Which is faster?](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) by Eric Lippert is always recommended reading for this sort of thing.

Comment: I'd be surprised if you could measure any difference between the first 3 methods. SQL Server query performance is affected by IO, not CPU additions.

Comment: @KapilaPerera why do you ask? Did you encounter a *real* problem? SQL query performance is affected by IO, indexing, RAM. The difference between 3 and 4 floating point operations is negligible compared to the cost of the overall query

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos im using this within a select query which will take bit more time to get the result.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually very easy to test it for yourself:

```
declare @number int = 104

declare @cnt int, @res int
declare @t1 datetime2(7), @t2 datetime2(7), @diff1 int, @diff2 int

set @cnt = 0
set @t1 = sysdatetime()
while @cnt < 1000000 begin
    set @cnt = @cnt+1
end
set @t2 = sysdatetime()
set @diff1 = datediff(ms, @t1, @t2)

set @cnt = 0
set @t1 = sysdatetime()
while @cnt < 1000000 begin
    set @res = (round( @number / 5,0 ) * 5 ) + 5    -- 1
    set @cnt = @cnt+1
end
set @t2 = sysdatetime()
set @diff2 = datediff(ms, @t1, @t2)
select @diff2-@diff1
```

Do this for all four cases, multiple times to eliminate the edge results, and compare.

A spoiler: 1 and 3 seem to be fastest and also almost identical in duration, 2 is slightly slower, and 4 is the slowest one.

Comment: Easy, yes. Meaningful - not at all. You are using clock time, which means that *anything* running in the backgroudn will affect the values you collect. It would be strange if you could measure any difference between any of these methods

Comment: To the point that you can get *negative* values for less than 100K iterations

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Not quite sure I see your point. You're opposed to any performance measuring, or you just have a problem with the methodology? Why would `round` being faster than `ceiling` be strange in your opinion? Thanks -

Comment: As Damien noted in the comments, check Eric Lippert's [Which is faster?](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/). Yes, the methodology is wrong because what you count can be affected by many things. In fact, with 100K iterations the first loop takes longer than the second loop. If you wanted to collect better statistics, you could have used `STATISTICS TIME ON`. As for speed differences, queries are IO bound. The difference between `CEILING` and `ROUND` is negligible compared to that.

Comment: Even on an in-memory table, where IO isn't such a big issue, you'd get better performance by using a natively compiled function than picking one or the other operation

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos So, you would use STATISTICS TIME because it is not affected by anything running in the background? Interesting, didn't know this was the case..